# Array properties nested in JSON object received as null

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs

I have Jersey PUT webservice which takes JSON/xml containing multiple arrays of objects-shown below as input.

```
{
"a" :  [{"p1":"x1"},{"p2":"x2"}],
"b" :  [{"q1":"y1"},{"q2":"y2"}],
"c" :  [{"r1":"z1"},{"r2":"z2"}]
}
```

In the service class this gets converted in to JavaBean input param. I have verified the xsd mappings are correct.
The issue is, when I invoke the service with JSON as input, in server side javabean I see only the first value getting populated correctly but the second and third are always null.
In other words, if I pass the json as listed in below different combination scenarios, I see the corresponding results as mentioned.

1. `{"a":[{}], "b":[{}], "c":[{}] }`
   Only "a" is received in JavaBean. "b" and "c" are received as null.
2. `{"b":[{}], "c":[{}], "a":[{}] }`
   Only "b" is received in JavaBean. "c" and "a" are received as null.
3. `{"c":[{}], "a":[{}], "b":[{}] }`
   Only "c" is received in JavaBean. "a" and "b" are received as null.

So it seems I get only first JSON key-value pair correctly no matter in what order I pass from client.

Thanks for helping out on this.

**More details below:**
This is legacy system and I do not have rights to share the actual code. The system is working fine with input of one-array, and requires to update, so it can accept multiple arrays in JSON as explained in question.

Here is what exactly different parts of the system looks like. Also I have verified that all the xml name-space and POJO properties etc are correct and annotated properly.

1) The CreateABCResource.java which implements PUT method:

```
//package x.y.z
//import javax.ws.rs.*..etc;

@Path("mypath")
public class CreateABCResource{

  @Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @PUT
  public AResponse doSomething(CreateABC createABC) {
    AResponse x = new AResponse();
    //business logic here
    return x;
  }
}
```

2) The input POJO CreateABC.java to service method PUT is as below:

```
//package com.x.y
//import ...;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CreateABC", namespace = "urn:x", propOrder = {
    "abc","def","pqr"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "createAbc", namespace = "urn:x")
public class CreateABC {

    @XmlElement(name = "abc", namespace = "urn:x")
    protected List<Abc> abc = null;
    @XmlElement(name = "def", namespace = "urn:x")
    protected List<Def> def = null;
    @XmlElement(name = "pqr", namespace = "urn:x")
    protected List<Pqr> pqr = null;

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String a;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String b;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String c;
    //and so on ...

    //getter setters...    
}
```

3) The input JSON from client/fiddler tool for testing:

```
{   
    "a": "some value a",
    "b": "some value b",
    "c": "some value c",
    "abc":[{},{}],
    "def":[{},{}],
    "pqr":[{},{}]
}
```

4) xsd containing the mappings for JAXB:

```
  <xs:element name="createAbc" type="CreateABC" />
  <xs:complexType name="CreateABC">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="abc" type="Abc" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="def" type="Def" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="pqr" type="Pqr" />
    </xs:sequence>
        <!-- THIS IS COMMENTED, BUT THIS ALSO DIDNOT WORK IN PLACE OF ABOVE sequence
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="abc" type="Abc" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="def" type="Def" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="pqr" type="Pqr" />
        </xs:all> 
        -->
    <xs:attribute name="a" use="required" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="b" use="required" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="c" use="required" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Abc"> 
    <!-- CORRET DEFINITON OF Abc is present here -->
  </xs:complexType> 
  <xs:complexType name="Def">
    <!-- CORRET DEFINITON OF Def is present here -->
  </xs:complexType>       
  <xs:complexType name="Pqr">
    <!-- CORRET DEFINITON OF Pqr is present here -->
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: json don't use xsd, I think you must be confused with xml here

Comment: You are right @gerrytan xsd is there just because the service supports xml  too, I have mentioned it in that context.

Comment: What library and java class are you using to de-serialize the Json?

Comment: jersey frameworks jars are used for this implementation

Comment: Thanks helping to edit it @BalusC !!! Appreciate your time much.

Comment: @Nitin Can you share your java bean ?

Comment: @Sashidhar I have added the details to the question. Thanks for your time. I have used package names like com.x.y and name space 'urn:x' just for demo only, the actual code has all correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code in input POJO:

```
@XmlElement(name = "abc", namespace = "urn:x")
protected List<Abc> abc = null;
@XmlElement(name = "def", namespace = "urn:x")
protected List<Def> def = null;
@XmlElement(name = "pqr", namespace = "urn:x")
protected List<Pqr> pqr = null;
```

with:

```
protected List<Abc> abc = null;
protected List<Def> def = null;
protected List<Pqr> pqr = null;
```

and it works.